# Cursor moving or jumping automatically while typing

Tags: 16.04, dell, inspiron

I am a beginner to Ubuntu and Linux so please help me in elaborated and simplified manner. Thank you in advance.

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed.
Whenever I type in any editor then the cursor automatically jumps to any part of the document. I don't know why it is happening.
I also use Windows 10, on that everything works fine.

Laptop specifications:

Dell Inspiron 5558 having Microsoft keyboard and touchpad
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
i5 5th generation processor and 8GB RAM.

If any more information required please let me know. 
Please solve mu issue. I have same typing style on both Windows and Linux so I can say that there are some problem in Ubuntu only.

Comment: If you have a touchpad, it's probably that you're accidentally  touching the touchpad with your palm and causing the cursor movements. Or a defecdtive Microsoft keyboard/touchpad. Find a setting or an application to disable the touchpad while you are typing.

Comment: It is working fine when I am using Windows 10. So I can say that touchpad is alright. Is it due to lack of drivers.

Comment: My typing style is same in both ubuntu and Windows